# Spanner emulator - hanging transaction

Tags: transactions, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

We are using spanner emulator in our sandbox environment. From time to time it happens that some transaction hangs out what is causing following error:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AbortedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: ABORTED: Transaction 37431 aborted due to active transaction 27078. The emulator only supports one transaction at a time.
```

The only way we found to make the spanner emulator working again after such an issue is to recreate a database (delete and create) what is quite annoying.

I've tried to kill all sessions listed by `gcloud spanner databases sessions list --database=db --instance=sand` but it is not helping.

Is there any way to abort/rollback a hanging transaction in spanner emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Executing a [Rollback RPC](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Spanner.Rollback) for transaction 27078 should do that. That being said, that is not necessarily straightforward:

1. Which client library / driver are you using? From the error message you posted, it seems to be Java. In that case you could try to construct a `RollbackRequest` and call the [Rollback](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/d093089bbc37d02b5e66305fab04e02e6a9c3a67/grpc-google-cloud-spanner-v1/src/main/java/com/google/spanner/v1/SpannerGrpc.java#L948) method in the generated client manually.
2. How/when does this happen? Normally, the Java client should automatically rollback any failed transaction. Or are you using some other driver than [the regular Java client](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner)?

Comment: Thank you from your answer. Yes it is java. We are using `DatabaseClient` (google-cloud-spanner) provided with `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-spanner` (but we are using it directly not by `SpannerTemplate`). I was not able find the rule when it happens. Our tests are running on this emulator and from time to time one transaction hangs out.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution? Seems like we have the same issue with hanging transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue using Python Client as well. After digging into the code, I found if an exception is raised in a transaction, the transaction will not be closed by the client. From my observation, the cloud Spanner works well on properly closing these hanging transactions on their own, but Spanner Emulator simply doesn't do that.